# what is the best solution of accessing action method in another controller asp.mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Items controller and Loans controller. I implemented qr code function within the system so now when a user goes in Items/details of a specific item there is generated automatically qr ready with encoded url of that specific item(Items/Details/id..
So next I wanted was when the user is redirected to that url of an item, to have option to "loan" it.. "Create New Loan" action method is placed in LoansController so I'm wondering how is best to solve the problem..?
So far what I've tried is just to copy/paste that action method "Create new Loan" from LoansController in the Items controller, and to set id as parameter for ItemId attribute when making new loan..
But after I did it, when a user clicks on a button "loan " the requests goes into "create new loan" action method of GET request in "ItemsController" and then the exception is thrown that it is expected model from type Loan not model of type Item.
The other thing I had in my mind is to have overloaded version of Create new loan in LoansController so to decide when the request is just normal one for creating a new loan from Loan Controller or it is coming from Items/Details with the specific id of the item..

I really hope to have described what I want to happen:
Currently the user can go in LoansController and use Create new Loan function where he can choose which item through dropdown..
The required functionality is when user uses qr and is redirected to items/details/id of a specific item's page to have option to "loan" it.
New loan action method Get req.:

```
public ActionResult CreateLoan(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Item item = db.Items.Find(id);

    if (item == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    // ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email");
    //ViewBag.ItemID = new T(db.Items.Where(x => x.State == true), "ItemID", "Name");

    //return RedirectToAction("CreateLoan", "Items", id);
    return View(id);
}
```

and here the same method for post req.:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateLoan([Bind(Include = "LoanID,ItemID,UserID,DateOut,DateDue,ReturnDate")] Loan loan, int? id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
        loan.ItemID = (item.ItemID);
        loan.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        loan.DateOut = DateTime.Now;
        loan.DateDue = loan.DateOut.AddDays(14);

        db.Loans.Add(loan);
```

and the view called after get req. and where the request throw ex..

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.Loan
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
@using WebApplication3.Models;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateLoan";
}

<h2>Create Loan</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to create this loan?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Loan</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOut)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOut)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateDue)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateDue)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReturnDate)
        </dt>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AspNetUser.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AspNetUser.Email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Item.Name)
        </dd>

    </dl>

   @using (Html.BeginForm())

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         {
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="CreateLoan" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("CreateLoan", "CreateLoan")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Views and Controllers are completely separate in MVC. so you can call ANY controller action from ANY view.
So technically you can make a call to the Loans controller action from your Item details view and then get the result or even redirect to a new view from there ...
So from your Detail view in the Create Loan link you can use something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Loan", "Create", "LoanController", new { id = "123" }, null)
```